# Question about Sobolev space estimate

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega:=(0,1)^2$, $g \in L^4(\Omega)$ and $v,w \in H^1_0(\Omega)$.

> Prove that $\int_\Omega gvw\leq ||g||_4||w||_{8/3}||v||_{8/3}\leq C||g||_4||\nabla v||_2||\nabla w||_2$

The first inequality follows easily applying Hoelder's inequality to $g$ and $vw$, then Cauchy Schwarz to $||vw||_{4/3}$. However, why do $w,v \in L^{8/3}(\Omega)$, and how do I get the second inequality?

I was thinking about applying some sort of Sobolev embedding theorem but I didn't find the right combination of indices... any idea?

Comment: You don't have many combination of indices to check. Is it true that $$\lVert v\rVert_{8/3}\le C \lVert \nabla v\rVert_2?$$ If it is true, then you are done; notice that it is an immediate application of Hölder that $\lVert vw\rVert_{4/3}\le \lVert v\rVert_{8/3}\lVert w\rVert_{8/3}$.

Comment: I'm stuck on exactly the first part of your comment, the second I used when deriving the first inequality (I called this "Cauchy Schwarz" in my question). Could you maybe give me more input? Thanks! @GiuseppeNegro

Comment: It does not seem like you really understood the Sobolev embedding, then. What do you get by using them?

Comment: I am asking so that we can find out where the difficulty lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, to prove the second inequality you must find an inequality of the form $$ \tag{1} \label{eq:1} \| u \|_{ 8 /3 } \leqslant C \| D u \|_{2} $$ for all $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$. (An inequality of this form is usually called a *Poincare inequality*.) The (standard) Poincare Inequality is

> Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ for some $1 \leqslant p <n$. Then $$\| u \|_{p^\ast} \leqslant C \|D u \|_p $$ where $$ \tag{2} \label{eq:2}p^\ast = \frac{pn}{n-p}$$ is the Sobolev conjugate of $p$ and $C>0$ is a constant depending only on $n,p$ and $\Omega$.

We can use the standard Poincare Inequality to prove \eqref{eq:1}. Indeed, let's choose $p$ such that $p^\ast = 8/3$ (using that $n=2$). Rearranging \eqref{eq:2}, we find the correct $p$ is $p=8/7$. Hence, the standard Poincare inequality implies \begin{align*}
\| u \|_{8/3} \leqslant C \| D u \|_{8/7}. 
\end{align*} Finally, it is well-known that if $\Omega$ is bounded then $\| \cdot \|_q \leqslant C \| \cdot \|_p$ for all $1 \leqslant q \leqslant p \leqslant \infty$ (this follows from Holder's inequality). Thus, $$\| u \|_{8/3} \leqslant C \| D u \|_{2}  $$ as required.

(Note: I've used $C>0$ to denote any constant, so the actual value of $C$ will be different every time I've used it.)